# Effects don't work after I install the Nvidia Drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, effects

I just installed ubuntu 11.10 64bit on my laptop and everything worked fine until I installed the nvidia driver (for a GeForce GT 525M).

After I install the driver and reboot, the effects like snap windows do not work.

In order to work I have uninstalled the driver.

Is there a way for me to use the driver and still have the effects available?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same video card and faced the same problem. Install bumblebee will solve the problem. I found no way to use the nvidia card. Instaed use bumblebee to disable nidia card and enable intergrated intel sandt bridge video card.

Installation of bumblebee

The recommended method to install Bumblebee on Ubuntu is by using its Stable Releases PPA, so install that one, refresh the packages list and install Bumblebee using the nvidia driver:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

for more instructions https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Upgrading-on-Ubuntu#wiki-install

Comment: you will find to use nvidia-xconfig command to configure your video card. But never use this command. It is not working for gt525m

Comment: After I install bumblebee, should I be able to use my graphics card?

Comment: No bumblebee disables your NVIDIA card and enables Intel graphics. This may solve your heat problem also(I think you can hear the sound of your laptop's cooling system now. This is because of the Nvidia card)

Comment: =/ I hope someday we can use our cards... thanks for the help!